# i want real time update in $.post without reload or refresh

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, .post

this is my PHP code_

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['show']))
{
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","server_name");

        $show = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM name1 ORDER BY date DESC");
        $html='';
        while($showE = mysqli_fetch_array($show)) 
        {
        $html.= '<h3>'.$showE['un_name'].'</h3>';
        $html.= '<div>'.$showE['un_name_dec'].'</div>';
        }
        echo $html;
       //End of while loop

}
```

this is jquery code_

```
$.post('preprocessor.php', '&show=', function(data) {
    $("#accordion").html(data);
    $("#accordion").accordion({
       collapsible: true,
       icons: {
            activeHeader: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
            header: "ui-icon-triangle-1-e"
        }
    });
    });
```

this is body_

```
<div id='accordion'>
</div>
```

i am not getting real time updates, everything is working, but the Ajax thing is not working... it works if i refresh or reload the page but not itself

Comment: Make sure to check here http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: are you calling query code_ repeatedly?

Comment: jqueryajax($.post, $.ajax, load() ), is known for realtime thing, but why it is not working, why everyone is using other javascript code for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `setTimeout`.

```
 $("#accordion").accordion({
       collapsible: true,
       icons: {
            activeHeader: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
            header: "ui-icon-triangle-1-e"
        }
    });
setInterval(makePostCall, 15000); // decide interval to fetch new updates. 15 sec for example

function makePostCall(){
$.post('preprocessor.php', '&show=', function(data) {
    $("#accordion").html(data);

    });
}
```

But this is not the proper way of doing this kind of stuff. Consider using [Ajax Push Engine](http://www.ape-project.org/)

Comment: dude it is not working, the accordion effect is working fine, but it is not fetching realtime updates from database(mysql)

Comment: jqueryajax, is known for realtime thing, but why it is not working, why everyone is using other javascript code for this,

Comment: jQuery ajax is not for real time update. It is used to *communicate* with server *asynchronously* without blocking anything or refreshing the page.

Comment: can you post html that is generate initially when according is working and updated html affter ajax response ?

Comment: should i use $.ajax because it has options for synchronous or asynchrnous( asynch:true)

Comment: `$.post()` , `$.get()` and other are `async` in nature by default.

Comment: what should i do now, $.ajax with asynch : false,? or

Comment: ajax is quite right. Don't need to change it. You are getting updates with `setInterval` and that's right. THere's some problem with your accodian.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting interval to call the code in certain intervals? All you need to do is,
on JavaScript add:

```
 setinterval(function(){/* do the post here */ },1000 /*this is time */);
```

Comment: it wont work, because if i do this the accordion effect won't work

Answer (score 0):

***it works if i refresh or reload the page but not itself***

For this you need to use `setInterval();` function which will check every specific time period which is given:

```
   setInterval(function(){
      $.post('preprocessor.php', '&show=', function(data) {
         $("#accordion").html(data);
         $("#accordion").accordion({
                   collapsible: true,
                   icons: {
                   activeHeader: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
                   header: "ui-icon-triangle-1-e"
                   }
         });
      });
   },5000); //<---- runs every 5000 ms
```

This will run every 5 seconds and will update the `#accordion` div.

Comment: i copied this code but the real time update is coming but accordion is not forming(accordion effect is not working)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$.post('preprocessor.php', {show:''}, function(data) {
$("#accordion").html(data);
$("#accordion").accordion({
   collapsible: true,
   icons: {
        activeHeader: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
        header: "ui-icon-triangle-1-e"
    }
});
},'html');
```